# Merge features before creating new shapefile in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm working with QGIS 3.10 A Coruña on MacOS 10.13 environment.
I've got the following code (provided by @Kadir Şahbaz in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385270/iterative-selection-of-features-and-export-to-shapefile-using-pyqgis/385283#385283)) to create new shapefiles from a loop selection of features for each different attribute value

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()

field_name = "CODNUT2"
idx = layer.fields().indexOf(field_name)
unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(idx)

folder = "/path/to/folder"

for value in unique_values:
    file_path = f"{folder}/_{value}.shp"
    layer.selectByExpression(f"{field_name}='{value}'")
    
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,
                                            file_path,
                                            'utf-8',
                                            layer.crs(),
                                            "ESRI Shapefile",
                                            onlySelected=True
                                            )
```

Now I need to merge all features in each selection before creating the shapefile. I've tried including the following chunk of code in line 12

```
layer.combine(layer.selectByExpression(f"{field_name}='{value}'"))
```

obtaining the following error message

```
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'combine'
```

How can it be mended?

Comment: You need to go to geometry level to be able to call `combine`. Please see here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243623/merge-selected-feature-pyqgis

Comment: I'd already consulted that post (and others) without success. Always get error messages of the kind '"TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object is not iterable"'

Comment: How do you want to handle the attributes of the combined lines?

Comment: none needed except the attribute value that was used for the selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I solved the problem by creating a temporary layer to save combined geometry and then write it to shp. I added the attribute which you use for the selection. You can delete if you do not want to have any attribute

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()

field_name = "CODNUT2"
idx = layer.fields().indexOf(field_name)
unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(idx)

folder = "/path/to/folder"

for value in unique_values:
    file_path = f"{folder}/_{value}.shp"
    layer.selectByExpression(f"{field_name}='{value}'")
    
    geom = None
    for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
        if geom == None:
           geom = feat.geometry()
        else:
           geom = geom.combine(feat.geometry())
        
    # Create temp layer to save the combined geom
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:25830", 
                      value, 
                      "memory")

    pr = vl.dataProvider()
    
    # Add Attr to temp layer 
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("CODNUT2", QVariant.String)])
    vl.updateFields()

    # Add geom to temp layer 
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(geom)
    f.setAttributes([value])
    pr.addFeature(f)
    vl.updateExtents()

    #QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
    
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl,
                                            file_path,
                                            'utf-8',
                                            vl.crs(),
                                            "ESRI Shapefile"
                                            )
```

Comment: @JesúsPinilla `pr.addAttributes([QgsField("CODNUT2", QVariant.String)]` you do not need to change this. Please be sure that you don't have ` onlySelected=True` while writing the shp. I just tested it with Polygon. It should work. If you still have problem, please print(geom) and add it here.

Comment: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(...., onlySelected=True ) >> Do you still have 'onlySelected=True` part in your code? If yes, please remove it and keep this part also like in my snipet.

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to see the layers with geometry if you uncomment `#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)` in your layer panel as expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118898/discussion-between-nil-and-jesus-pinilla).